# currentUser do firebase está retornando nulo

Tags: javascript, react, firebase, react-native

Estou fazendo um projeto que consiste em criar dois aplicativos, estou usando o firebase como base de dados e ambos estão usando a mesma base de dados, o primeiro aplicativo está funcionando normalmente, porém o segundo está dizendo que o **currentUser está nulo**.

Primeiro Aplicativo:

```
async function signUpPet(
    namePetField,
    typePetField,
    agePetField,
    racesPetField,
  ) {
    let uid = await firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let key = await firebase.database().ref('pets').child(uid).push().key;

    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref('pets')
      .child(uid)
      .child(key)
      .set({
        nm_pet: namePetField,
        ds_type: typePetField,
        ds_age: parseFloat(agePetField),
        ds_races: racesPetField,
        dt_createPet: format(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
      })
      .then(async (snapshot) => {
        let data = {
          key: key,
          namePet: namePetField,
          typePet: typePetField,
          agePet: snapshot.val().ds_age,
          racesPet: racesPetField,
          dateCreatePet: snapshot.val().dt_createPet,
        };
        setUser(data);
      });
  }
```

Segundo Aplicativo:

```
async function signUpTimeVetSignUp(
    monday,
    tuesday,
    wednesday,
    thursday,
    friday,
    saturday,
    sunday,
  ) {
    let uid = await firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    let key = await firebase.database().ref('timeVets').child(uid).push().key;

    await firebase
      .database()
      .ref('timeVets')
      .child(uid)
      .child(key)
      .set({
        vetmonday: monday,
        vettuesday: tuesday,
        vetwednesday: wednesday,
        vetthursday: thursday,
        vetfriday: friday,
        vetsaturday: saturday,
        vetsunday: sunday,
      })
      .then(() => {
        let data = {
          mondayVet: monday,
          tuesdayVet: tuesday,
          wednesdayVet: wednesday,
          thursdayVet: thursday,
          fridayVet: friday,
          saturdayVet: saturday,
          sundayVet: sunday,
        };
        setTimeVet(data);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

difícil dizer só com este código. provavelmente há algo errado com a autenticação do segundo app. lembrando que logo que recarregar a página `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` costuma ser nulo. pois ainda não realizou autenticação.
tente utilizar:

```
let firebaseUser = null;
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
  if (user) {
    firebaseUser = user;
  } else {
    console.log('usuário não logado');
  }
});

async function signUpTimeVetSignUp(
    monday,
    tuesday,
    wednesday,
    thursday,
    friday,
    saturday,
    sunday,
  ) {
    let uid = firebaseUser.uid;
    let key = await firebase.database().ref('timeVets').child(uid).push().key;
    // ...
```